# Show users role wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

So I am trying to show the users roles from Wordpress and seem to be struggling a bit. The core name of the role is still subscriber but I can show everything but the role and I am a little bit stuck.

I am not sure what to get in order to get that information?

```
 <?php
    $args1 = array(
     'role' => 'committee',
     'orderby' => 'user_nicename',
     'order' => 'ASC'
    );
     $committee = get_users($args1);

    echo '
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th style="padding: 10px;">Title</th>
        <th style="padding: 10px;">Name</th>
        <th style="padding: 10px;">Email Address</th>
        <th style="padding: 10px;">Telephone Number</th>            
      </tr>';

    foreach ($committee as $user) {
    echo '  
      <tr>
        <td style="padding: 10px;">' .$user->job_title .'</td>
        <td style="padding: 10px;">' . $user->display_name .'</td>
        <td style="padding: 10px;">'.$user->user_email . '</td>
        <td style="padding: 10px;">'.$user->tel_number . '</td>
      </tr>';

     }
    echo '</table></ul>';
    ?>
```

Comment: You're wanting to get all the users for a specific role? I guess it's not clear in your question ...

Comment: You can have user capabilities but not role unless you have explicitly set the role. And please elaborate your question more.

Comment: Basically all I am doing is showing a list of my users. down the left column I was wanting to show their role in the table too? Didnt know if it was possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
    // If you don't already have a WP_User object
    $user = new WP_User( $user_ID );

    // Then you can get the role(s)
    if ( !empty( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
        foreach ( $user->roles as $role )
            echo $role;
    }
```

And a handy helper function to get the localized role name:

```
function get_role_display_name( $role_id ) {
    global $wp_roles;
    if ( !isset( $wp_roles ) ) $wp_roles = new WP_Roles();

    return isset( $wp_roles->role_names[ $role_id ] )
            ? $wp_roles->role_names[ $role_id ]
            : $role_id;
}
```

Comment: So where does that go?

Comment: Don't expect on StackOverflow that people will do work for you. Think a little bit, try something and I am sure you'll understand where it goes.

Comment: I found this code off another site that you posted and was struggling with it also.